# Yaesu VX-7R clock is running very fast

Tags: ht, yaesu

I just noticed the clock on my Yaesu VX-7R is running *very* fast. I noticed this a few days ago, where it would be days ahead. I would reset the time to the second and then, again, hours or days ahead.

I'm not sure when this started happening, or if it has always been this way. The unit was purchased new a few years ago. I guess I never had the clock on the display at all, but I've recently tweaked the settings to show the clock on the main display at all times.

Finally, today I set it and saw that it was running *minutes* fast. It would be 2-3 minutes ahead after only one minute of actual wallclock time.

One hint on an old forum suggested doing a **Microprocessor Resetting** as per the instructions in the manual, but this did not change the behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Original poster and answerer here. This Answer is incorrect. Once the clock starts doing this a full battery reset will only help for shorter and shorter increments. The correct answer is to replace the battery, as per https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/21914]

Self-answering because I did not find this anywhere else, though in retrospect it was sort of obvious. I thought that putting it here might make this more accessible to future internet spelunkers.

Even though a **Microprocessor Resetting** (VX-7R manual, p.80) did not work as I previously mentioned, it occurred to me that some non-volatile settings might be maintained across a reset.

So, I pulled the battery and let it sit for a minute or so before replacing the battery. Then I did a `[4]` `[BAND]` `[V/M]` reset and set the clock to the correct time. It's been keeping accurate time since.

Comment: Amazing. I wonder what else was incorrect when it was in that state. Was the transmit frequency ok?

Comment: @tomnexus I was able to hear my local repeaters (input even for local hams) at the exact right frequencies so I _think_ that was ok. I'm still working on my basic qualifications in Canada so I can't legally check xmit. Though, you remind me that I'm deaf to the 70cm repeaters at the exact same bearing (same antenna array), so I should retry those.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the same problem on my vx7 a couple of years ago. I think the problem comes from the internal battery BT3001 which needs a replacement, because this problem started after almost a decade.. My fix to the problem is to exchange the battery with the FB23 pack for a couple of minutes, and then put the original pack again. Sometimes a system reset (not a complete reset) is required.

Comment: This is the correct answer. My original answer to this question which I self-accepted was wrong. A battery reset only delays the inevitable. Buy a new Yaesu battery from the mothership and the clock will run correctly again.